# What is the algorithmic complexity of this solution?

Tags: algorithm

I'm practicing leet code questions and want to understand more fully how to determine Big O notation. What is the algorithmic complexity of my solution to the following problem?

**O(n^2) ?** For every item in n I could loop an additional n[i] times. Or is it **O(n)** ?

Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned at the first index of the array.

Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that position.

Determine if you are able to reach the last index.

Input: [2,3,1,1,4]

Output: true

Explanation: Jump 1 step from index 0 to 1, then 3 steps to the last index.

```js
var canJump = function(nums) {

  let validIndices = {};
  for(let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let currentNum = nums[i]; 
    if(currentNum + i >= nums.length - 1) {
      validIndices[i] = true;
    } else {
      while(currentNum > 0) {
        if(validIndices[i + currentNum]) {
          validIndices[i] = true;
        }
        currentNum--;
      }
    }
  }

  return !!validIndices[0];
};
```

Comment: O(n²) does not sound right, as the n[i] are not the same as n. However, in this case the maximum jump length is at least bounded by n (does not make sense to jump further than there are steps), so it is at least not more than O(n²).

Comment: Yes, it's O(n^2) in the worst case when the array is like [n, n-1, n-2, ..., 3, 2, 1, 0]. It would be faster in the average case if you had a `break` from the inner loop once you already set `validIndices[i] = true;`, but still O(n^2) in the worst case.

Comment: Having said that, the problem can probably be solved in O(n), unless I'm missing something. Just scan the array in reverse, note if there is a stretch of 0 (cells that you have to jump over), and whether there is a n[i] in front of those large enough to bridge the gap.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @tobias_k the value at position n[i] is the max number of jumps allowed from that position. I initially thought I could just check to see if n[i] was large enough to bridge the gap but you still need to account for jumps from the max jump to the min jump at that position. So I don't think your proposed solution would work unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying - which is very possible! This was my first attempt - it works, but its slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious, since the `n[i]` is not directly related to `n`, but since every `n[i]` can be up to `n`, the total number of steps, your algorithm would be O(n²). Of course, if you have additional information, such as each `n[i]` being smaller than some `k`, then it would only be O(nk).

---

However, the `can_jump` function can be implemented in O(n), too, as you do not have to check *all* the possible `n[i]` jumps! You just have to check the longest possible jump and update the maximum reachable position accordingly, and return whether you reach the end or get stuck in the middle.

```py
def can_jump(nums):
    max_reachable = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if i > max_reachable:
            return False # current pos not reachable
        max_reachable = max(max_reachable, i + nums[i])
        if max_reachable >= len(nums) - 1:
            return True  # end is reachable

can_jump(nums=[2,3,1,1,4]) # True
can_jump(nums=[2,1,0,0,4]) # False
```

If, on the other hand, there is a restriction like "at most `m` jumps", then this will not work.

Comment: Maybe you could explain something to me. Given nums = `[2,2,0,1,1]` when we get to index 2 which is value 0, max_reachable will still be two. Why is this?